# SQL: How to pull Customer IDs who have done action A, but never action B?

Tags: sql

Here's what I need to pull: All customers who ONLY ordered online (ie, customers 1 and 3).

Given the way the table is structured (customer 4 appearing twice on the list), I'm struggling to OMIT customer 4 from this data pull, because they bought online and in store.

Data:

Customer 1 - purchased online

Customer 2 - purchased in store

Customer 3 - purchased online

Customer 4 - purchased online

Customer 4 - purchased in store

Here's my code and I'm definitely still getting customer 4 in the mix, but not sure how to exclude them. The full data I'm working with is much larger, of course.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table.customer_id)
FROM table
WHERE ((table.purchase_channel='store') 
    AND NOT (table.purchase_channel='online'))
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses to make things cleare, i.e. simply do `SELECT DISTINCT table.customer_id...`.

Comment: Thank you! Always love to see how I can clean up the code.

Answer (score 3):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.customer_id
from t
group by t.customer_id
having sum(case when t.purchase_channel = 'store' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.purchase_channel = 'online' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

I find this structure very convenient for a wide range of conditions.  For your specific conditions, you can shorten this to:

```
select t.customer_id
from t
where t.purchase_channel in ('store', 'online')
group by t.customer_id
having min(t.purchase_channel) = 'store' ;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

Use "not exists":

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE not exists(
   select 1 from table 
   where customer_id = t.customer_id 
    and  purchase_channel='online')
```

You should try all the variants suggested here. For small tables it doesn't matter, but for large table it makes a big difference. E.g. in Sql Server I find "not exists" usually generates the best query plan. Make sure you have an index on (customer_id, purchase_channel).
In large, distributed systems "not in" may work better.

Answer (score 0):

using not in

```
select customer_id from table t
     where   t.customer_id not in
    (
      SELECT table.customer_id
        FROM table
        WHERE  
            table.purchase_channel='online'
    ) and t.purchase_channel='store'
```